# How to correctly open and close a SQLite Database in a C# class

Tags: c#, sqlite, resources, system.data.sqlite

Ok so i have a DBConnect class in which I have all my methods relating to the database of my program. I understand that connections are a relatively expensive resource so what is the correct way of opening and closing my database file.

This is what i'm currently using
I simply create the connection in the constructor and then open and close it when needed in the methods. Does this correctly return the connection to the pool? Also would it be better if I put a using(conn) in my methods.

```
public class DBConnect
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = null;
    public DBConnect()
    {
        string connStr = @"Data Source=tests.db; Version=3;";
        conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
    }

    public DBConnect(string connStr)
    {
        conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
    }
    public DataTable DBSelect(string query)
    {
    /* 
     * Uses a select query to store data from the database into 
     * a datatable 
     */
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught exception: " + err.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }//DBSelect
```

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If you want to keep your connection open then you can keep `SQLiteConnection conn` at class level. Then you should close connection using some method. Otherwise `DBSelect` is just fine. All you need to use `using` statement inside this method, no need for class level conn object.

Comment: If you your app does not access db from multiple threads you can actually have your connection open for the whole process lifetime. In other case just let the pooling to does its job.

Comment: personally, I would use 'Using' and let the connection be returned to the pool, why tie up a resource during times you are not doing anything?

Comment: So should I just put a 'using' in all my methods with an empty constructor?